# Wrong remote port shown in TCP Connections

Tags: windows, java, port

We have a RFID application in Java, by default it will listen on TCP port 5084. Which is the default port for LLRP (Low Level Reader Protocol).

The application is on Windows Server 2019. The application suddenly stopped communicating with the RFID Readers.

Investigation on the remote system showed in Task Manager > Resource Monitor > TCP Connections: The remote port the application is connecting to is port 7, but it should be 5084.

What could be the reason for the remote application connecting to port 7?

Comment: could it (the Java application) be using port 7 (echo) as a check to see if the server/device is there before trying to connect to port 5084?

Comment: Capture packets as they leave the RFID reader. Use a passive tap if needed. What port is shown there?

Comment: By default the application is connecting to 5084 port using the API. I tried the telnet to port 5084 which is working fine.

Comment: You don't specify which host should listen on tcp/5084. Is it the application on Windows Server 2019?

Comment: Have you investigated to see if the Java application is listening on port 7 when everything IS working?

Comment: I am sure the port defined to connect in application is 5084.

Comment: @GregAskew Yes the application is on Windows server 2019

Comment: The remote endpoint "connects"  to and the host "listens" on TCP/5084. If you need to specify that the host is listening on the wrong port you should specify that. Otherwise we will assume the endpoints are connecting to the wrong port. If something is listening on tcp/5084 as you stated, you need to run `netstat -ano | findstr :5084` and confirm the process id that is listening on 5084 is the correct and expected process.